# How to populate BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView ?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, treeview, objectlistview

I just downloaded [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), and have an issue with populating it.

I got list of `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Data { get; set; }

  public MyObject(int id, int parentId, string name, int data)
  {
     Id = id;
     ParentId = parentId;
     Name = name;
     Data = data;
  } 
}

List<MyObject> list = List<MyObject>();
```

I need to populate a `TreeListView` with `MyObject` elements ([Using TreeListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-a-treelistview)).
Also I need one column been filled with `.Data` property.
I can not populate it even as a `list`(all items on the same level) and without any columns, I've tried this:

```
this.myTreeListView.SetObjects(list);
```

and this:

```
this.myTreeListView.Roots = list;
```

But the tree is still empty, nothing has been populated, what am I doing wrong ? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find some useful "getting started" information regarding the TreeListView [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#recipe-treelistview). Make sure you understand and use that concept.

However, there is no mention that you also have to add **at least one column** (you can do this in the designer). So this might be your problem. The TreeListView tutorial assumes that you already know how to use the ObjectListView.

I suggest you also read the general [getting started](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html) guide, especially the "mental gear shift" section.

> The crucial part of using an ObjectListView is configuring it. Most of this configuration can be done within the IDE by setting properties on the ObjectListView itself or on the columns that are used within the list. Some configuration cannot be done through properties: these more complex configurations are done by installing delegates (more on this later). **Once the columns and control are configured**, putting it into action is simple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Their documentation is horrible!

Comment: @Jerry: I found it informative most of the time and there are some useful examples. Especially the Demo project is a nice code reference on how to accomplish some not-so-obvious stuff, maybe take a look at that if you haven't.

Comment: I took a look at them, but it still takes some time to learn, especially for things not documented or in examples.

Comment: The stupid thing is that the TreeListView demo page does not show full source code (just explanations) and the link "download source" is linked to the project source, not the demo source of the page. There are two zip files.  The normal one does not include examples, and the "full" version includes examples. The problem is, there are many files and I could not figure out where the TreeListView sample code was.

Answer (score 5):

this way i do it. here i am giving my full code. have a look and ask me if u have any confusion. thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private List<Node> data;

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeData();
            FillTree();
        }

        private void InitializeData()
        {
             string connString = "Data Source=xxx.xx.xx.xx\\test;Initial Catalog=Test;User id=sa;Password=test;";
            string sql = "USP_RefundRequested";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            data = new List<Node>();

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ds.Relations.Add("ParentChild",ds.Tables[0].Columns["JID"],
                        ds.Tables[1].Columns["CID"]);

                        DataRelation orderRelation = ds.Relations["ParentChild"];
                        foreach (DataRow order in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Subtotals for Order {0}:", order["OrderNumber"]);
                            Node parent1 = new Node( order["JID"].ToString(), "", "","","");

                            foreach (DataRow oChild in order.GetChildRows(orderRelation))
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine("Order Line {0}: {1}", orderDetail["OrderLineNumber"], string.Format("{0:C}", orderDetail["Price"]));
                                parent1.Children.Add(new Node("", oChild["EntryDate"].ToString(),
                                    oChild["RefundDate"].ToString(),
                                    oChild["ActionBy"].ToString(),
                                    oChild["Comments"].ToString()
                                    ));
                            }
                            data.Add(parent1);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void FillTree()
        {

            this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).Children.Count > 0; };
            this.treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).Children; };

            // create the tree columns and set the delegates to print the desired object proerty
            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn JIDCol = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Job ID", "JID");
            JIDCol.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).JID; };

            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn EntryDatecol = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Entry Date", "EntryDate");
            EntryDatecol.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).EntryDate; };

            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn RefundDatecol = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Refund Date", "RefundDate");
            RefundDatecol.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).RefundDate; };

            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn ActionBycol2 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Action By", "ActionBy");
            ActionBycol2.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).ActionBy; };

            BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn Commentscol3 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("Comments", "Comments");
            Commentscol3.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Node)x).Comments; };

            // add the columns to the tree
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(JIDCol);
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(EntryDatecol);
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(RefundDatecol);
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(ActionBycol2);
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(Commentscol3);
            // set the tree roots
            this.treeListView1.Roots = data;

            treeListView1.Columns[1].Width = 142;
            treeListView1.Columns[2].Width = 142;
            treeListView1.Columns[3].Width = 179;
            treeListView1.Columns[4].Width = 667;
            treeListView1.Columns[treeListView1.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2;

            treeListView1.ExpandAll();
        }


    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string _jid = "";
        public string JID
        {
            get { return _jid; }
            set { _jid = value; }
        }

        //public int _cid = 0;
        //public int CID
        //{
        //    get { return _cid; }
        //    set { _cid = value; }
        //}

        public string _entrydate;
        public string EntryDate
        {
            get { return _entrydate; }
            set { _entrydate = value; }
        }


        public string _refunddate;
        public string RefundDate
        {
            get { return _refunddate; }
            set { _refunddate = value; }
        }


        public string _actionby = "";
        public string ActionBy
        {
            get { return _actionby; }
            set { _actionby = value; }
        }

        public string _comments = "";
        public string Comments
        {
            get { return _comments; }
            set { _comments = value; }
        }

        public List<Node> _Children = null;
        public List<Node> Children
        {
            get { return _Children; }
            set { _Children = value; }
        }

        public Node(string JID, string EntryDate, string RefundDate, string ActionBy, string Comments)
        {
            this.JID = JID;
            //this.CID = CID;
            this.EntryDate = EntryDate;
            this.RefundDate = RefundDate;
            this.ActionBy = ActionBy;
            this.Comments = Comments;
            this.Children = new List<Node>();
        }
    }
}

ALTER PROC  USP_RefundRequested  
AS  

BEGIN  
;WITH  Hierarchy AS  
(  
    SELECT DISTINCT  JID  
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) EntryDate  
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) RefundDate  
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Comments  
            ,CAST(NULL AS BIT) Refund  
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) ActionBy  
            ,nLevel = 1  
   ,0 AS CID  
    FROM refundrequested  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT   CAST(NULL AS INT) JID  
            ,E.EntryDate  
            ,E.RefundDate  
            ,E.Comments  
            ,E.Refund  
            ,E.ActionBy  
            ,H.nLevel+1  
   ,H.JID  AS CID  

    FROM refundrequested   E  
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID  

)  

--SELECT *  
--FROM Hierarchy  WHERE CID=0
--ORDER BY COALESCE(JID, CID) DESC, nLevel  

SELECT * into #tmpHierarchy FROM Hierarchy

SELECT JID,EntryDate,RefundDate,ActionBy,Comments,CID  
FROM tmpHierarchy  WHERE CID=0
ORDER BY COALESCE(JID, CID) DESC, nLevel  

SELECT JID,EntryDate,RefundDate,ActionBy,Comments,CID  
FROM tmpHierarchy  WHERE CID>0
ORDER BY COALESCE(JID, CID) DESC, nLevel  

drop table #tmpHierarchy
END  
go
```

Comment: Thank you! That's best example that i've found and really worked. But still, what to do, if i have two different classes in model, not just Node? For example: File and Folder. 
 Maybe combine them to one with parameter enum  <item_type>  = {Folder = 0, File = 1}; ?